# How to conditionally run a test?

Tags: nunit

I have the following (using NUnit):

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class SmokeTest : BaseTest
    {
        [Test(SmokeTest)]
        public void ShouldAlwaysRun()
        {
            //Tests,Assertions,etc
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldNotRunIfSmoke()
        {
            //Tests,Assertions,etc
        }

    }
```

I have a TestFixture per functional area of my project.  I'd like to be able to run a "smoke test" that only runs those tests marked as "SmokeTest" (maybe via attribute).  I originally had smoke tests in their own file but was literally copying and pasting other tests into that file - I'd like to keep things DRYer.

The end goal is that I can somehow identify when I'm running smoke tests, so that:

- If I am running smoke tests, run only those marked as such
- If I'm not running smoke tests, run all tests, including smoke tests

How can this be achieved using NUnit?

EDIT: I just found Categories:

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2.10

This would be great - but how do I specify from Test Explorer or Build Configs when to run only a certain category?  I'll leave the question as it stands in case there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Right yoiu are. Categories is exactly what you need.

> This feature is accessible by use of the /include and /exclude arguments to the console runner and through a separate "Categories" tab in the gui.

So you can enable just one category in both GUI NUnit test runner & console test runner. The other categories (and tests without cetegories) will be disabled.

Not sure whether Visual Studio Test Explorer (I assume you mean VS one) supports NUnit categoties.
But you definitely can specify `/include MyCategory` parameter in a build config to run just a subset of all the tests.

Answer (score 0):

When using ReSharpers Testrunner, there is a "Options" dropdown where you can group your tests by categories.
[image: Resharper TestRunner - Group by: Categories]